# Why is the Number() function not working when I use it this way?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, integer, numbers

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  // your code here
  let nums = num.toString();
  let sum = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
       Number(nums[i]);
      console.log(typeof nums[i]);
      sum += nums[i];
  }

  return sum;
}


var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
```

Can someone explain why Number(nums[i]) does not change the type of the variable. Or any other way to solve this problem? The function is supposed to take in an integer value and add all the digits and return an integer.

When I tried to run the code i couldn't get the string to convert back into a number and would just add the value of sums to the front of the string.

Comment: `Number` returns a new value. You are discarding this value. Primitive values are not changed in-place; that’s not how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 2):

You are not saving the value returned by `Number(nums[i])`. But since here you are not using it more than once, you can just add it to the sum without assigning it to a variable.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  // your code here
  let nums = num.toString();
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(nums[i]);
  }

  return sum;
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
```

Comment: Also, you can use a string's [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to avoid the ceremony of the iteration variable. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d62uL4wb/

Answer (score 2):

`Number` does not change the value it's used on. (It couldn't when used on a string, anyway, since strings in JavaScript are immutable.) It just returns a number. So you have to use that return value.

Try this instead:

```
for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    sum += Number(nums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, change `sum += nums[i];` to `sum += Number(nums[i]);`. Reason: When you add a string to a number, the number is first converted to a string, and a string concatenation is performed.

Here is a functional programming approach to your question:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  return num.toString()        // convert number to string
    .split('')                 // split into array of chars
    .reduce((acc, val) => {    // reduce array to sum of items
      return acc + Number(val)
    }, 0);
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
```

Functional programming makes code more extensible, modular, reusable, performing, and testable.

Into to functional programming in JavaScript:
https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript

`.reduce()` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Here is the same with a map reduce approach:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  return num.toString()        // convert number to string
    .split('')                 // split into array of chars
    .map(char => Number(char)) // change each char in array to number
    .reduce((acc, val) => {    // reduce array to sum of items
      return acc + val
    }, 0);
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
```

Intro to map reduce: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d